# multilanguage site with sub folder

Tags: php, multilingual

Please help me with php file that must redirect to correct language.
the site architecture is 
site.com/en
site.com/fr

my cod:

```
<?php
$sites = array(
"en" => "/en/index",
);

$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

if (!in_array($lang, array_keys($sites))){
$lang = 'en';
}
// перенаправление на субдомен
header('Location: ' . $sites[$lang]);
?>
```

Comment: could you please explain your problem? what doesn't work?

Comment: ok so if user with English language browser go to

site.com/fr/file
site must redirect him to en version site
site.com/en/file

please tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to append the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variable, that contains the path relative to the document root, to your language folder.

If your path were `site.com/fr/file`, this variable would contain `/fr/file`. When you remove the first part of this part, you get the 'language-independent' path of the called script, that you can append to the desired language directory.

If your path is as you described, you could try the following solution (untested!):

```
<?php
$sites = array(
"en" => "/en",
);

$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

if (!in_array($lang, array_keys($sites))){
$lang = 'en';
}

$path_to_script = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 3);

header('Location: ' . $sites[$lang] . $path_to_script);
?>
```

EDIT: to clarify the approach:
If the site is `site.com/fr/123/index.php`, the variable `$path_to_script` will then contain `/123/index.php`, the script directory without the leading language dir.
You can then append this to the desired language dir and get the path you wanted: `/en/123/index.php`

Comment: sorry for the question but what is this $path_to_script ?

Comment: this variable will contain the path to the script, with the language directory removed. if your site is `site.com/fr/folder/index.php`, the variable will contain `/folder/index.php`. I have edited my answer for better understanding.

Comment: when i start the site.com i redict to without site name and lang /endex.php

Comment: sorry for my english...I understood thet i must to create two files. the first which will redirect the main page
en/
fr/
the second which will redirect internal page
/fr/123/index.php
/en/123/index.php yes?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you could create one page, that redirects the main page to /en or /fr and another page, that redirects the internal page(s). But if you have many subpages I would outsource the redirection process to a function or a file, that gets imported.

Comment: I have just tested the solution on my local machine, it worked like charm: localhost/fr/index.php redirects to localhost/en/index.php as expected.

Comment: how can I make the redirect if the user enter EN or FR in browser?

Comment: please try to reformulate your question.

Comment: so i crate two files: first in index thet must redirect site.com/en to site.com/fr and in catalog sitecom/EN/ i create file thet must redirect from en to fr  but when i go to site.com i have an error: Invalid redirect page

Answer (score 0):

`/en/index` should be `/en/index.php` except if you are using Apache's mod_rewrite (not by default). Please provide more details of what is not working so we can help you more.

EDIT:
Furthermore, you could give the user the option of choosing language as 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' might not be set. In that case, the only choice would be English, which would limit your public.

Some people even recommend about geolocalization, but I find it good enough to add a little drop down menu with languages.

Comment: ok so if user with English language browser go to

site.com/fr/file
site must redirect him to en version site
site.com/en/file

please tell me how can i do this?

Comment: For that first tell us what's not working with your code. Then that's a really common problem, so you should be able to google it easily. [This link](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1252-php-redirect-depending-on-specific-language) should work, it was just the first one I found. But if you want more help from us, you REALLY need to answer Stefan S and me about 'what's not working with your code?'

Comment: i don't need a language selection...i get the browser information about language $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

Comment: its code redirect user from site.com/fr/file
to site.com/en

but must redirect to site.com/en/file

Comment: But some browsers don't send this information, so any non-English person that sees the page and has the language not set is forced to see it in English with this method.